# How to read and edit specific line of a text file in C

Tags: c, text, readfile

I am trying to make a method that takes as a parameter the number of a line and the file in which I want the data

```
char SearchLine(int numberLine,char[100] fileName)
{
  char line[256];
  int nline=numberLine;
  int i=0;
  FILE *ifp;
  ifp = fopen(fileName, "r");


  while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", &line) == 1)
  {
    if(i==nline)
    {
        printf("\n%d",i);

    }
    else if(i<nline)
    {
        i++;
    }

  }
  printf("\n%s",line);
  printf("\n%s\n\n",i);

  system("pause");
  return line;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, "%s", &line)` I don't think there should be an & in front of `line`. the %s indicates that it is looking for a `char*` type, and line is `char*` type.

Comment: Duplicate of so many existing questions. And the usual answers all mention "you cannot write back an edited line in the middle of a file" somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't been particularly clear about what you are trying to do, but to write to a specific line, just move to the start of that line (either by reading each line until you reach the one you want or by using `seek()`), and then write your data.

The problem is that typical text files have lines of different lengths. Therefore, if the data you write to that line is more or less than the data that was on the line before, then you'll mess up your data.

The only way to make this work reliable is:

1. Require that every line in your file is always a known, fixed length.
2. Or copy the entire file, writing the new line as you write than line to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want a function that you can pass a `filename` and a `numberLine` to as arguments and then have the function return that line for editing, then you can use something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 256

char *SearchLine (int numberLine, char *line, char *filename);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. usage: %s filename.\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char linebuf[MAXC] = {0};
    int linenum = argc > 2 ? atoi (argv[2]) : 3;

    SearchLine (linenum, linebuf, argv[1]);

    printf ("\n line[%3d] : %s\n", linenum, linebuf);

    return 0;
}

/* read line number 'numberLine' from 'filename' into 'line'.
 * Returns line on success, NULL otherwise. (numberline is zero based)
 */
char *SearchLine (int numberLine, char *line, char *filename)
{
    int index = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "SearchLine() error: file open failed '%s'\n",
                filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {
        if (index == numberLine)
            return line;
        if (index > numberLine)
            break;
        index++;
    }
    fclose (fp);

    *line = 0;
    return NULL;
}
```

**Note:** the line numbers are *zero* based (e.g. `0, 1, ...`), adjust if you want them to run from `1`.

Looking at `SearchLine` **note** an array to hold the line is passed as one of the arguments. Line has `MAXC` characters (adjust as required). By passing an array to the function, you eliminate the need to allocate space in `SearchLine`. The function simply reads each line in the file until the counter `index == numberLine` and then returns the line. If if the number given is greater than the number of lines in the file, then line is set to the empty-string and `NULL` is returned.

A quick example would be:

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_linenum dat/captnjack.txt 1

 line[  1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow

$ ./bin/fgets_linenum dat/captnjack.txt 4

 line[  4] :
```

If you were looking to handle/edit the line in a different manner, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Jonathan's answer. 
To write to a file, one must open the file in read/write mode, i.e.,

```
ifp = fopen(filename, "r+");
//"r", as in your case, it opens the file in read-only mode.
```

This would open the file in read/write mode provided that the file exists. As a good programming practice, always check if the file is existing: `if(ifp != NULL) {}`.

One major thing is that you SHOULD always close the file that you've opened. `fclose(ifp);`